# Check finite line interception C

Tags: c, line, interception

Im trying to make a function that checks if two finite lines cross each other ( returns 0 or 1 ).

First of all I declare these structs

```
typedef struct _Point{
    double x;
    double y;
}point;
typedef struct _Line{
    int numVertex;
    point *vertex;
}line;
```

Than, here I start the function.

```
int lineInterceptsLine(line L1, line L2){
    double b1,b2,a1,a2,xi,yi;

    // First of all Im using both vertex to get each line equation in the form -> y=bx + a. And I start making an exception because if both vertex have the same value for x, b will be 0, but in the equation Ill endup dividing by 0 and will cause error.
    if((L1.vertex[1].x-L1.vertex[0].x)==0){
        b1 = 0; // Check line1
    }else{
        b1 = (L1.vertex[1].y-L1.vertex[0].y)/(L1.vertex[1].x-L1.vertex[0].x);
    }
    if((L2.vertex[1].x-L2.vertex[0].x)==0){
        b2 = 0; // Check line 2
    }else{
        b2 = (L2.vertex[1].y-L2.vertex[0].y)/(L2.vertex[1].x-L2.vertex[0].x);        
    }
    a1 = L1.vertex[0].y-b1*L1.vertex[0].x;
    a2 = L2.vertex[0].y-b2*L2.vertex[0].x;

    // Now I have both lines equation

    if(a1==a2){ 
        if(b1==b2){ 
        }else{
            if(((L1.vertex[0].x<0)&&(L1.vertex[1].x>0)&&(L2.vertex[0].x<0)&&(L2.vertex[1].x>0)) ||
               ((L1.vertex[0].x>0)&&(L1.vertex[1].x<0)&&(L2.vertex[0].x>0)&&(L2.vertex[1].x<0))    ) {
                return 1;
            }else{
                 return 0;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }else if(b1==b2){
        return 0;        
    }else{
        xi = (b2-b1)/(a1-a2);
        yi = ((a2*b1)-(a1*b2))/(a2-a1);
        if(((L1.vertex[0].x-xi)*(xi-L1.vertex[1].x))>=0 && 
                ((L2.vertex[0].x-xi)*(xi-L2.vertex[1].x))>=0 && 
                ((L1.vertex[0].y-yi)*(yi-L1.vertex[1].y))>=0 && 
                ((L2.vertex[0].y-yi)*(yi-L2.vertex[1].y))>=0 )
            {
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why some tests are not working, like the ones with the following values:

```
   L1.vertex[0].x=0;
    L1.vertex[0].y=1;
    L1.vertex[1].x=3;
    L1.vertex[1].y=1;
    L2.vertex[0].x=2;
    L2.vertex[0].y=2;
    L2.vertex[1].x=2;
    L2.vertex[1].y=0;
```

If you can't find the problem and know an algorithm that works, it would be great as well. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vertical lines will cause challenges, recommend another approach: **Parametrized lines**  L(t) = (Ax,Ay) + t*(Dx,Dy)

```
// Pseudo code
// D slope
D1 = (L1[1].x - L1[0].x, L1[1].y - L1[0].y)
D2 = (L2[1].x - L2[0].x, L2[1].y - L2[0].y)

// Parametric line
L1(t1)  = (L1[0].x, L1[0].y) + t1*D1
L2(t2)  = (L2[0].x, L2[0].y) + t2*D2

// Simultaneous  equation
// Solve the 2 equations with 2 unknowns t1, t2 
(D1.x     -D2.x)(t1)    =   (L2[0].x – L1[0].x)
(D1.y     -D2.y)(t2)    =   (L2[0].y – L1[0].y)

// If determinant is 0, lines are parallel.  Special handling
// Else if 0.0  <= t0 & t1  <= 1.0, lines intersect
```

---

Details

`L1[0]` and `L1[1]` are 2 points that define a *segment*.  (OP uses `L1.vertex[0].x`, I use the shorten `L1..x notation`.) `L1(t1)` is a function defines a *line* that goes through those two points as a function of `t1`.  Notice when `t1` is 0, `L1` is `(L1[0].x, L1[0].y)` and when `t1` is 1, `(L1` is `L1[1].x, L1[1].y)`.  Similar for L2.  Now we have 2 *Parametric line* equations as a function of `t1` and `t2`.

The next step is to find the values of `t1` and `t2` that generate the same `(x,y)` point for both lines, in other words, the intersection.  Thus:

```
D1.x  = L1[1].x - L1[0].x
D1.y  = L1[1].y - L1[0].y
D2.x  = L2[1].x - L2[0].x
D2.x  = L2[1].y - L2[0].y
L1[0].x + t1*D1.x = L2[0].x + t2*D2.x
L1[0].y + t1*D1.y = L2[0].y + t2*D2.y
// or
DX = L2[0].x - L1[0].x
DY = L2[0].y - L1[0].y
D1.x*t1 - D2.x*t2 = DX
D1.y*t1 - D2.y*t2 = DY
// or in matrix notation
(D1.x - D2.x)(t1)  = (DX)
(D1.y - D2.y)(t2)  = (DY)
//
d = D1.x*D2.y - (-D2.x)*(-D1.y)
// if d is 0, lines are parallel and need to determine if co-incident or distinct.
t1 = ( DX(-D2.y) - DY*(- D2.x) )/d
t2 = ( DX(-D2.x) - DY*(- D1.x) )/d
```

Finally we have `t1` and `t2`.  If there are *both* in the range 0 to 1, then the intersection occurred in the original segments.  This answers the question "if two finite lines (segments) cross each other?"

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn't understand these operations: `(D1.x   D2.x)(t1)` and `L1(t1)`. Can ou explain your last commend as well?

`// Else if 0.0  <= t0 & t1  <= 1.0, lines intersect` Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

1. on the assignment part, we know that you want to know is two **line segment** cross or not.
2. I don't know the numVertex means in the struct you defined, and the comment is really hard to read for me, so I rewrite one, I hope it can help u.

first, two points(start point and end point) can determine a straight line, 
If two line segment crossed(line A and line B), we can see two points of line A is on the different sides of line B (or one point is a port of line B), else they are not crossed.

```
typedef struct {
    int x, y;
} point;

typedef struct {
    point sp;    // start point
    point ep;    // end point
} line;

int is_segment_line_cross(line l1,  line l2)
{
    int sidea, sideb, side;     

    int l1_x_vector = l1.sp.x - l1.ep.x;
    int l1_y_vector = l1.sp.y - l1.ep.y;

    int l1_l2_ax_vector = l1.sp.x - l2.sp.x;
    int l1_l2_ay_vector = l1.sp.y - l2.sp.y;

    int l1_l2_bx_vector = l1.sp.x - l2.ep.x;
    int l1_l2_by_vector = l1.sp.y - l2.ep.y;

    sidea = l1_x_vector * l1_l2_ay_vector - l1_y_vector * l1_l2_ax_vector;
    sideb = l1_x_vector * l1_l2_by_vector - l1_y_vector * l1_l2_bx_vector;

    side = sidea * sideb;

    if (side <= 0) {
       return 1;
    } else {
       return 0;
    }

}
```

Why? You can get more from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069420/check-if-two-line-segments-are-colliding-only-check-if-they-are-intersecting-n)

Answer (score 0):

I'd restructure the code entirely if I were you. You can lose efficiency quickly the way that you're doing it now. Try something like this;

```
/* 2D point */
typedef struct _Point{
  float x;
  float y;
} point;
/* 2D line data */
typedef struct _LineSegmentData{
  point* a;
  point* b;
} lineSegmentData;

/* General shape structure */
typedef struct _Shape shape;
typedef struct _Shape{
  void* shapeData;
  char(*shapeIntersect)(shape*,shape*);
};
    /* Shape hierarchy data */
typedef struct ShapeTree{
  shape* left;
  shape* right;
} shapeTree;
```

Or something similar, then use a bounding box hierarchy and function pointers to make everything a lot more simple. Or, if you're not a big fan of function pointers, just use the same points you'd use to define a segment to define a box, and have a `char isLine` variable as part of the structure.

The efficiency of your code will go way way up (binary search), and be way easier to debug.

All the best!