# Find out if 2 lines intersect

Tags: c++, geometry, linear-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you detect where two line segments intersect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect)
>   [Determining if two line segments intersect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977491/determining-if-two-line-segments-intersect)

Given are two lines l1=((A0, B0), (A1, B1)) and l2=((A2, B2), (A3, B3)); Ax, Bx are integers and (Ax, Bx) specify the starts and ends of the lines.

Is there a algorithm using only integer arithmetic that determines if l1 and l2 intersect? (Only a Boolean answer is needed.)

**My own approach** was to compute a point near the intersection point with fixed-point arithmetic. The solution (a, b) was then substituted in the following equations:

I:  abs((A0 + a * (A1-A0)) - (A2 + b * (A3-A2))) < tolerance 
II: abs((B0 + a * (B1-B0)) - (B2 + b * (B3-B2))) < tolerance

My method should return true if both I and II evaluate to true.

**My C++-Code:** 
*vec.h*:

```
#ifndef __MY_VECTOR__
#define __MY_VECTOR__
#include <stdarg.h>
template<typename VType, unsigned int dim>
class vec {
private:
    VType data[dim];
public:
    vec(){}
    vec(VType v0, ...){
            data[0] = v0;
            va_list l;
            va_start(l, v0);
            for(unsigned int i=1; i<dim; ++i){
                    data[i] = va_arg(l, VType);
            }
            va_end(l);
    }
    ~vec(){}
    VType& operator[](unsigned int i){
            return data[i];
    }
    VType operator[](unsigned int i) const {
            return data[i];
    }};
    template<typename VType, unsigned int dim, bool doDiv>
    vec<VType, dim> helpArith1(const vec<VType, dim>& A, long delta){
            vec<VType, dim> r(A);
            for(unsigned int i=0; i<dim; ++i){
                    r[i] = doDiv ? (r[i] / delta) : (r[i] * delta);
            }
            return r;
    }
    template<typename VType, unsigned int dim>
    vec<VType, dim> operator*(const vec<VType, dim>& v, long delta) {
        return helpArith1<VType, dim, false>(A, delta);
    }
    template<typename VType, unsigned int dim>
    vec<VType, dim> operator*(long delta, const vec<VType, dim>& v){
        return v * delta;
    }
    template<typename VType,unsigned int dim>
    vec<VType, dim> operator/(const vec<VType, dim>& A, long delta) {
        return helpArith1<VType, dim, true>(A, delta);
    }
    template<typename VType, unsigned int dim, bool doSub>
    vec<VType, dim> helpArith2(const vec<VType, dim>& A, const vec<VType, dim>& B){
        vec<VType, dim> r;
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<dim; ++i){
            r[i] = doSub ? (A[i]-B[i]):(A[i]+B[i]);
        }
        return r;
    }
    template<typename VType, unsigned int dim>
    vec<VType, dim> operator+(const vec<VType, dim>& A, const vec<VType, dim>& B){
        return helpArith2<VType, dim, false>(A, B);
    }
    template<typename VType, unsigned int dim>
    vec<VType, dim> operator-(const vec<VType, dim>& A, const vec<VType, dim>& B){
        return helpArith2<VType, dim, true>(A, B);
    }
    template<typename VType, unsigned int dim>
    bool operator==(const vec<VType, dim>& A, const vec<VType, dim>& B) {
            for(unsigned int i==0; i<dim; ++i){
                if(A[i]!=B[i]){
                            return false;
                    }
            }
            return true;
    }
    template<typename VType, unsigned int dim>
    bool operator!=(const vec<VType, dim>& A, const vec<VType, dim>& B) {
            return !(A==B);
    }
    #endif
```

*line.h*:

```
#ifndef __MY_LINE__
#define __MY_LINE__
#include "vec.h"
unsigned long int ggt(unsigned long int A, unsigned long int B) {
    if(A==0) {
        if(B==0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return B;
    }
    while(B!=0) {
        unsigned long int temp = A % B;
        A = B;
        B = temp;
    }
    return A;
}
#define ABS(n) ( ((n)<0) ? (-n) : (n) )
struct line {
    vec<long int, 2> A, B;
    explicit line(long int iA_0, long int iA_1, long int iB_0, long int iB_1) :
        A(vec<long int, 2>(iA_0<<8, iA_1<<8)),
        B(vec<long int, 2>(iB_0<<8, iB_1<<8)){}
    vec<long int, 2> slope() const{
        vec<long int, 2> temp = A-B;
        if(temp[0]<0) {
            temp[0] = -1 * temp[0];
            temp[1] = -1 * temp[1];
        }
        return temp/ggt(ABS(temp[0]), ABS(temp[1]));
    }
};
bool intersect(line l1, line l2) {
    const long int epsilon = 1<<4;
    vec<long int, 2> sl1 = l1.slope(), sl2 = l2.slope();
    // l2.A + b*sl2 = l1.A + a*sl1
    // <=> l2.A - l1.A = a*sl1 - b*sl2  // = (I, II)^T
    // I': sl2[1] * I; II': sl2[0] * II
    vec<long int, 2> L = l2.A - l1.A, R = sl1;
    L[0] = L[0] * sl2[1];        R[0] = R[0] * sl2[1];
    L[1] = L[1] * sl2[0];        R[1] = R[1] * sl2[0];
    // I' - II'
    long int L_SUB = L[0] - L[1], R_SUB = R[0] - R[1];
    if(ABS(R_SUB) == 0) {
        return ABS(L_SUB) == 0;
    }
    long int temp = ggt(ABS(L_SUB), ABS(R_SUB));
    L_SUB /= temp; R_SUB /= temp;
    // R_SUB * a = L_SUB
    long int a = L_SUB/R_SUB, b = ((l1.A[0] - l2.A[0])*R_SUB + L_SUB * sl1[0])/R_SUB;
    // if the given lines intersect, then {a, b} must be the solution of
    // l2.A - l1.A = a*sl1 - b*sl2
    L = l2.A - l1.A;
    long x = ABS((L[0]- (a*sl1[0]-b*sl2[0]))), y = ABS((L[1]- (a*sl1[1]-b*sl2[1])));
    return x<epsilon && y < epsilon;
}
#endif
```

*main.cpp*:

```
#include "line.h"
int main(){
    line A(0, 0, 6, 0), B(3, 3, 4, -3);
    bool temp = intersect(A, B);
    return 0;
}
```

(I am not sure if my intersect function works for all lines, but with the test data I used so far it returned with the correct result.)

Comment: @Eduardo I'm assuming segments. Lines would be much easier.

Comment: I think the easiest way would be finding out where on the lines (of which the segment is a segment) the intersection lies, then answering whether those points are in both respective segments.

Comment: @Tinctorius With only integer arithmetic?

Comment: @leemes You only need fractional arithmetic, which involves a pair of integers.

Comment: @Tinctorius Oh, I see, you're so right... Can be done without float arithmetic. Nice! ;)

Comment: You should probably [rename your include guard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: Not a duplicate: restriction to integer only math, and no need for point of intersection, make this distict from both linked duplicates.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is possible. We want to check whether both endpoins of l1 are on different sides of l2, and both endpoints of l2 are on opposite sides of l1.

To check on which side of l1=((A0, B0), (A1, B1)) a point (A, B) lies, we take:

- an arbitrary normal vector N perpendicular to the line; one such vector is (B1-B0, A1-A0)
- the vector P from the start of the line to the point (A, B), which is (A-A0, B-B0)

We then compute the dot product:

N · P = (A-A0, B-B0) · (B1-B0, A1-A0) = (A-A0) * (B1-B0) + (B-B0) * (A1-A0)

We're only interested in the sign: if it's positive, the point is on one side of the line; if it's negative, it's on the other. As you see, no floating point arithmetic required.

We can take advantage of the fact that numbers with opposite signs, when multiplied, always yield negative. So the full expression to determine whether two line segments ((A0, B0), (A1, B1)) and ((A2, B2), (A3, B3)) intersect is:

```
((A2-A0)*(B1-B0) - (B2-B0)*(A1-A0)) * ((A3-A0)*(B1-B0) - (B3-B0)*(A1-A0)) < 0
&&
((A0-A2)*(B3-B2) - (B0-B2)*(A3-A2)) * ((A1-A2)*(B3-B2) - (B1-B2)*(A3-A2)) < 0
```

### Test Code

Some C++ code to test the above calculation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

struct Point {
    int x,y;
};

bool isIntersecting(Point& p1, Point& p2, Point& q1, Point& q2) {
    return (((q1.x-p1.x)*(p2.y-p1.y) - (q1.y-p1.y)*(p2.x-p1.x))
            * ((q2.x-p1.x)*(p2.y-p1.y) - (q2.y-p1.y)*(p2.x-p1.x)) < 0)
            &&
           (((p1.x-q1.x)*(q2.y-q1.y) - (p1.y-q1.y)*(q2.x-q1.x))
            * ((p2.x-q1.x)*(q2.y-q1.y) - (p2.y-q1.y)*(q2.x-q1.x)) < 0);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if(argc != 9) {
        std::cout << "Call as " << argv[0] << " <p1.x> <p1.y> <p2.x> "
                  << "<p2.y> <q1.x> <q1.y> <q2.x> <q2.y>" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Point p1 = {.x = atoi(argv[1]), .y = atoi(argv[2])};
    Point p2 = {.x = atoi(argv[3]), .y = atoi(argv[4])};
    Point q1 = {.x = atoi(argv[5]), .y = atoi(argv[6])};
    Point q2 = {.x = atoi(argv[7]), .y = atoi(argv[8])};

    if(isIntersecting(p1,p2,q1,q2)) {
        std::cout << "Segments intersect" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Segments do not intersect" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Results:

```
$ ./intersection_test 0 0 10 10 0 10 10 0 # example from the comments
Segments intersect
$ ./intersection_test 0 1 2 1 1 2 1 0
Segments intersect
$ ./intersection_test 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0
Segments do not intersect
$ ./intersection_test 1 1 5 3 3 4 7 2 # q touches but not intersects at p2
Segments do not intersect                             
$ ./intersection_test 1 1 5 3 3 4 6 2
Segments intersect
```

Comment: I tried your solution first with the following dot-implementation:
template<typename VType, unsigned int dim>
long int dot(const vec<VType, dim> &a, const vec<VType, dim> &b) {
        long result = 0;
            for(unsigned int i=0; i<dim; ++i) {
                result += a[i] * b[i];}
 return result;
} But it does not work with the segments ((0,0), (10, 10)) and ((0, 10), (10, 0))

Comment: Of course I had to make a typo in there :) Better now? If not, split it up into a few helper functions to make it easier to follow.

Comment: It's still not working, but don't worry - after a good night sleep I will find the error.

On a side node: Thank you all, for the quick and detailed answers.

Comment: Argh, I forgot to flip the x,y coordinates in the code. Shouldn't be coding after 11 PM. Rolled back to the pseudocode first version so it stands at least a chance of being correct :)

Comment: The pseudocode given in this answer doesn't work. ((0,0), (10, 10)) and ((0, 10), (10, 0)) is false, but should be true.

Comment: I can't edit my previous comment, but wantedd to add that you can find working examples in this thread: You can find working examples in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect

Comment: Sorry about that. Feel free to fix it up if you find the error! The general idea should still be right though.

Answer (score 1):

Two line segments intersect iff their lines intersect and the endpoints of each line segment are on opposite sides of the other segments line.  At least in 2d.

Two lines intersect is an easy question in 2d.

Which side of a line a point is on is also easy.

Neither require non integer math.

I would estimate a dozen or three lines for some general geometry code, then a 6 to 10 line solution?  Plus language boilerplate.  And some zero length corner case checks.

Note I am distinguishing lines from segments.