# Determine if rectangle contains or has intersection with path

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have an image and all text is marked by rectangles around each word. I need to select some words by marking them with finger. To do so, I draw a line on the image. I need to check which rectangle contains that line.

how I can check if a rectangle contains that line.

[image]

i want get rectangle on which line as drawn

**Edit**
This has been implemented in Google Translator App. I need exact same behavior.

Comment: You have an array of rectangles....right?

Comment: yes i have list of rectangles

Comment: Alright, there are 2 possibilities....first if the line starts in the rectangle and ends right there...the second is if the line cuts one line of rectangle.
I try to right an answer for you.

Comment: I think, you can use this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977491/determining-if-two-line-segments-intersect/4977569#4977569)

Comment: Test if your touch line segment intersects with any rect's 4 side line segments. See the [duplicate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect/565282#565282) for the algorithm and code.